# how do i get back on my user-microposts branch of github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I accidentally swtiched back to the master branch whilst doign rails tutoial. now i can't get back. below is my terminal output including th emistake and subsequent attempts to return to the branch. none of which worked

```
owen358:~/workspace $ cd sample_app  #<-- cd into "user-microposts" branch
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app (user-microposts) $ cd sample_app   #<--accidentally did same command and went back into master branch
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app/sample_app (master) $ cd sample_app
bash: cd: sample_app: No such file or directory
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app/sample_app (master) $ git branch   #<-- this command supposed to list all branches but did nothing
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app/sample_app (master) $ git checkout user-microposts   #<-- my attempt to return to user-microposts branch
error: pathspec 'user-microposts' did not match any file(s) known to git.
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app/sample_app (master) $ git branch
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app/sample_app (master) $ git show-branch #<-- another way i found that is supposed to list all the branches and didnt work
No revs to be shown.
owen358:~/workspace/sample_app/sample_app (master) $
```

how can i return to the user-microposts branch i was working on and why do my commands not do anything?

Comment: Can you show me a `ls -al`?

Comment: Also a `git --version`. I suspect you've just gone too far down a directory but what is puzzling me is that my git still prints out branches even if I'm in a subdirectory.